# How do I expand ALL collapsed code regions in VS2005

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

This is very frustrating, if I search for a variable in a vb file in VS2005 it won't find it if the code blocks are collapsed.  How is this helpful?

So I tried to expand ALL code blocks inside the file, without success.

I've tried Ctrl+M but that only expands 1 block, and I've tried Ctrl+M, L but that expands the top class only and not the regions inside.

Can someone help me, what should be a productivity booster is actually hindering me in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press Ctrl+M, P.

Alternatively, go to Find Options and check Search Hidden Text.

Answer (score 1):

"Find Options" on the find dialog, "Search Hidden Text"